# comparing cubics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Suppose I have cubic functions $$f(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3$$ and $$g(t)=b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2+b_3t^3$$ where $t\geq 0$.

Let $$h(t)=f(\alpha t)+g((1-\alpha)t), \alpha\in[0,1].$$ What conditions do I impose on the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ for $$(1)\space{} h(t)\geq f(t)?$$ $$(2)\space{} h(t)\geq g(t)?$$

Initially, in (1) I considered that $h(t)-f(t)\geq 0$. But I got stuck because I cannot infer from there that the coefficients of $h(t)-f(t)$ would each be greater than or equal to zero, right? Is there a special theory that needs to be used to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: It'll probably be easier if you write the cubics in the Bernstein basis.

Comment: I am not familiar with Bernstein polynomials but I'll try to look it up. Thank you.

Comment: @lhf Am I doing this right? As what I understood from reading on Bernstein polynomials: given a polynomial $h(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_nt^n$ of degree $n$ has a Bernstein polynomial $$B(x)=b_0B_{n,0}+b_1B_{n,1}+\cdots+b_nB_{n,n}$$ where $B_{n,i}=nC_i x^i (1-x)^{n-i}$. And $B(x)\geq 0$ if $\forall i, b_i\geq 0$. So I let $A(x)=B(x).$ Equated the coefficients of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$. The only result I got is that $d_2\geq 0$. As for the other coefficients, I still couldn't get how to infer conditions on their values.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $h(t)$ in condition $(2)$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, it should be $h(t)$. Thank you for calling me out. I'll put an update.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Notice that $\alpha t+(1-\alpha)t=t$ so the restriction for $\alpha\in [0,1]$ is not a restriction for $t\in\Bbb R$. You want to have 
$$\begin{cases}h(t)-f(t)\ge 0\\h(t)-g(t)\ge 0\end{cases}$$

Excepting the case $a_3=b_3$ you have  these two equations are cubics so they can not be always non negative. Hence it is necessary both equation be of the second degree

It follows $\color{red}{a_3=b_3}$ is a first condition. The second one is easy to get for quadratic equation (the minimum must be greater or equal than zero which involve a straightforward calculation).